# Setting gaps between bars in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know how to control the space between bars in the below code reading data’s from a file.  Is there any approach to adjust/resize the space (not the width of the bars) between bars?

> **Input file**:
>
> 1   4500
>   2   5000
>   3   3000
>   4   4000
>   5   1000
>   6   5000

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pylab as plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy, scipy, pylab, random
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'): continue
        row = line.split()
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
ax = plt.subplot(111)


plt.ylim(0, 6000)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(500))
plt.xlim(0+0.5, 7-0.5)


bars=plt.bar(x,y, width=0.2, color='blue', edgecolor='black', align='center', linewidth=0.5)

bars[0].set_facecolor('gray')
bars[1].set_facecolor('orange')
bars[2].set_facecolor('green')
bars[3].set_facecolor('yellow')
bars[4].set_facecolor('cyan')
bars[5].set_facecolor('deeppink')


labels=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='45', rotation_mode='anchor', ha='right')

plt.ylabel('Values (m)', fontsize=7)

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
  ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.97)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.98)


plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=0)


plt.savefig("plot.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: if the bar width is fix, and you want to change the gap between bars, the only way is to change the width of the figure, is this your want?

Comment: Or increase the x range - `plt.xlim(0+0.5, 10-0.5)`

Comment: The gap is determined by the width of the bars and the X axis ticks, or points:  gap=(x2-x1)-width

Comment: Changing the width of the figure and increasing the x range didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (I've tried matplotlib version 3.5.2) is in this line of code:

```py
x.append(float(row[0]))
```

If you do something like

```py
x.append(float(row[0]) + 0.5 / float(row[0]))
```

you will notice the change of space between the bars. In the line above I'll add a component to the x-coordinate and that component will be a bit smaller if the value of row[0] increases.